# How to print in a node the \coordindex multiplied by a value?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, coordinates

I would like to print in a node the \coordindex multiplied by a value. Is it possible?

now:

```
node [
            some code... 

        ] {$\coordindex$}
```

after (?)

```
node [
            some code... 

        ] {$\coordindex * value $}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. I think it might be something as simple as `\pgfmathparse{\coordindex*value}\pgfmathresult`...

Comment: Hi @darthbith: Thank you very much for this fast answer, that's exactly what I need :-) I will put this as answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

```
\pgfmathparse{\coordindex*value}\pgfmathresult
```

Comment: Just used this, but instead of multiplying I just added a constant value. Now I have a decimal number instead of a single digit.
So `\coordindex+1` is `1.0` for example, instead of just `1`.
How can I work around this?

Comment: Alright, a little to late to edit my own entry I found a solution.
Just used `\pgfmathprintnumber`.
Looks like this now:
`$\pgfmathparse{\coordindex+1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$`